# Обход защиту от парсинга (Python)

Tags: python, json, парсер, requests

вот код который возвращает ошибку

```
import requests

link = 'https://www.kraken.com/api/internal/cryptowatch/assets?preferred_asset_name=new&limit=10&sort=market_cap&window=undefined&tradable=all&search=&asset=eur&ascending=false&position=0'


responce = requests.get(link)
data = responce.json()
print(data)
```

походу на сайте какая-то защита от парсинга

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу результат вывода, чтобы те, кто мог бы помочь не тратили время (или не передумали) на проверку работоспособности и проблемы

Comment: Вместо ответа в формате json, приходить ответ в формате html вот таким содержимым "One More Step Please complete the security check to access Kraken.com Please stand by, while we are checking your browser...". А так как это не json вылазит ошибка. Если в запросе отправить куки и хендлеры то вполне нормальный ответ приходить в виде json {"result":{"rows":[{"rank":1,"name":"Bitcoin","asset":"BTC"....